# javascript try to find the rabbit code

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid, addeventlistener, selectors-api

So the exercise in the book is as follows:
Try to turn this into a "catch the rabbit" game where the rabbit moves whenever you mouse over it. After 4 attempts to mouse over, it should show the "No Easter Eggs" message. After 20 attempts, it should show "Humans Suck". Create the page with a single div element with a fixed width and height and a border around it include a p element right underneath which contains an idso you can use it as output. Use the onmousemove event on the div to count how many times the event was triggered and displays the count in the p element. 
First off I had a mini type exercise I tried here's the code:

```
    <body>
    <div>
     <h1>Catch the Easter Bunny to get your egg!</h1>
     <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit" onmouseover="MyFunction1()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
     <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit2" onmouseover="MyFunction2()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
     <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit3" onmouseover="MyFunction3()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
     <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit4" onmouseover="MyFunction4()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
     <h2 id="noeggs">No Easter Eggs for You</h2>
     <h2 id="yousuck">Humans suck!!!</h2>
    </div>
<script>
    function MyFunction1(){
    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('rabbit2').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit4').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    function MyFunction2(){
    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('rabbit3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit4').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    function MyFunction3(){
    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit2').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('rabbit4').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    function MyFunction4(){
    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit2').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit4').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    }
 </script> 
</body>
```

This worked fine but the actual exercise wants it into 1 function MyFunction not Myfunction1, MyFunction 2 etc... and ofcourse 20 different rabbit images and all that and if you get it within 4 tries you get the "humans sucks to appears" or if its over 20 times you get "no easter eggs for you" so then I tried the following:

```
     This is the html:
 <body>
<div>
<p></p>    
<h1>Catch the Easter Bunny to get your egg!</h1>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r1" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r2" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r3" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r4" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r5" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r6" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r7" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r8" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r9" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r10" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r11" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r12" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r13" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r14" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r15" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r16" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r17" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r18" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r19" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="r20" onmouseover="MyFunction()" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<h2 id="noeggs">No Easter Eggs for You</h2>
<h2 id="yousuck">Humans suck!!!</h2>
</div>
<script>

function MyFunction(){

    document.getElementByTagNames('img').addEventListener('mouseover', onmouse);

    document.getElementById('r1').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r2').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r3').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r4').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r5').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r6').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r7').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r8').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r9').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r10').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r11').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r12').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r13').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r14').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r15').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r16').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r17').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r18').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r19').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('r20').style.visibility = "hidden";

    var code = document.querySelectorAll('img');

    function onmouse(){
        if(code == (document.querySelectorAll('img').style.visibility = 'visible')){
         for(i = 0; i < code; i++){
              code[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

I've tried many times to do this but, even when I have the visbility hidden all my rabbits show. I don't know what's wrong with the program I've tried at least ten different attempts. This is a report because someone of my previous post basically spammed it with his own opinions which had nothing to do with my programming and problem. which I am trying to understand. I'm guessing maybe my for loop will not detect an array through querySelector('img'); and also I've use a css file to hidethe humsn suck and what not with color:white if your wondering. my addEventListener I think is also a problem. Please help and make me understand what is wrong with my script. to make this work. Again please do not comment upon opinions of my coding just answers that may help me to solve this problem I'm having. thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: SO does not exist to do your homework for you.

Comment: The question is I've tried everything it does not work. even hiding the rabbits. when it did it with just four rabbits and four different MyFunctions it works but I need to have it in one MyFunction not, onmouseover=MyFunction(), onemouseover=MyFunction2(), etc...

Comment: @gravityplanx this is an exercise to understand javascript and to learn from it. regardless it would not even be any concern of what it goes towards this site is about learning. and when someone will help with it I will LEARN.

Comment: I have a feeling my flaw is within my addEventListener and my function which is where the flaw is I used the querySelector for the Array but in my for loop I think it does not recognize that.

Comment: This site is about providing a resource when you feel like you've exhausted **all other resources**.  It is meant to handle specific problems that can not easily be solved elsewhere.  If you have a specific question about a hiccup in your code, absolutely ask it... but this isn't the place to request someone complete an entire project for you.

Comment: ell i'm not asking to complete an entire project, I have attempted to complete this EXERCISE, this is out of a book I purchased. So please can someone help me on this.

Comment: I personally know html/css and Java, but to be a good web designer I have had a small company which now someone has asked me to do certain things with forms and such, which toproduce the results I realized I have to learn javascript therefore I purchased a few books of javascript nad am going through them. Now can we please get back to the point I did not post this to get into a debate on what I am using this for I posted it for knowledge purposes, gravityplanx if you can help please help otherwise cease and desist on further conversings of the procedings respectfully. Thank You.

Comment: @gravityplanx alright since I can't post for 4 days I reupdated the  current post now tell me what do you see that I'm doing wrong when I make it separate functions it'll work but the thing says it wants it all in one function?!?! what do u propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This worked fine but the actual exercise wants it into 1 function MyFunction not Myfunction1, MyFunction 2 etc... and ofcourse 20 different rabbit images and all that

So instead of this:

```
function MyFunction1(){
    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('rabbit2').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rabbit4').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

What you want to do is pass it an input variable to your function.  You define the input like this:

```
function MyFunction(inputVariable){
```

and then when you later call the function, you will pass in some value to it;

```
onmouseover="MyFunction(1)"
```

So in this specific call of the function, inputVariable will be equal to 1.  If you later called it as `MyFunction(7)`, inputVariable would be equal to 7.

By providing an input variable, we can change the behavior of our function:

```
if(inputVariable == 1){
    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
} else {
    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

etc.

As for getting your CSS effects to work properly, I see two main culprits;

1. Some of your function names are misspelled.  This is something that will cause an error, so to verify  if you have things spelled correctly, simply check your developer tools!  For most browsers, you can access the console by pressing the F12 key on your keyboard, then go to the "console" tab on the window that shows up.  If an error occurs in your code (such as a spelling mistake) it should show up there and make you aware of the problem.
2. In a few cases, you use `document.get` style commands which return arrays.  If you're not yet familiar with arrays, I would suggest doing some research on them, as they are very important.  You will need to use a `for` loop in order to go through every item of those arrays and apply the CSS style that you want.

Hope this helps you.  :)

Comment: so I tried that out but it got me all the bunnies and then one remaining:
  function MyFunction(inputVar){
            document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
document.querySelectorAll('img')[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.querySelectorAll('img')[2].style.visibility = 'hidden';
up to 20 then made a if statement right under it:
if(inputVar == 0){
                document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'visible';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('rabbit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }

Comment: In my html:
<img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit" onmouseover="MyFunction(0)" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
         <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit1" onmousemove="MyFunction(1)" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
         <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit2" onmousemove="MyFunction(2)" alt="Catch the rabbit"/> and so on up to MyFunction(19) but still doesn't work

Comment: I am aware of the console but the errors don't show it's just something with my code and prolly my onmouseout or onmouseover I'm not sure

Comment: I ran your code in my browser, and I definitely did see errors in the console log.  I think it was just a missing `s` in one of the function names.  If your current browser isn't showing those errors, I would suggest downloading a different browser to use.  Chrome and Firefox are both fairly good, from my experience.

Comment: Just ran it again, and can verify again, yes, there is a typo.

Comment: yeah i'm using internet explorer

Comment: lemme try again using another browser

Comment: x Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

That is the error I'm getting but when I go to elements I Can't find it and in netbeans it doesn't show any errors. btw is the actual program working for you. for when you hover over a rabbit img(or any image you've displayed) it then shows an other image in a different area and when u hover over that it shows the image in another spot etc...?

Comment: cause I hover over the image and then it's gone but no other image is shown.

Comment: I would really love to help you more, but I don't currently have the time.  This is part of why it's important for questions on SO to be small and specific, so that they can be answered quickly.   I think at this point, my answer here addresses your main concern of "How do I make a single function that has 20 different behaviors", but if you want additional help with other aspects of the problem I would suggest starting a new question about the other *specific* problems you're facing.  That way other people will see the question and offer help as well (whereas right now, only I am seeing this)

Comment: no it worked I did this with your code took me a minute to realize what u were saying:
<img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit0" onmouseover="MyFunction('rabbit0')" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit1" onmouseover="MyFunction('rabbit1')" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
<img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit2"onmouseover="MyFunction('rabbit2')" alt="Catch the rabbit"/> 
then used:
function MyFunction(theId){ 
document.getElementById(theId).style.visibility = "hidden";
var randRabbit = Math.round(Math.random() * 20);
document.getElementById("rabbit"+randRabbit).style.visibility = "visible";}

Comment: thank you bro. much appreciated.